# Access grunt server from local network

Tags: testing, networking, mobile, gruntjs

I need to access my grunt server from the local network for mobile device testing.

My grunt file has the following:

```
    server: {
        src: 'server',
        dist: 'dist/server',
        views: 'server/views',
        protocol: 'https',
                ip: '127.0.0.1', 
                port: 3000,
    },
```

When I run grunt it will open up at 127.0.0.1:3000 on that computer, but hitting :3000 from a mobile device doesn't work. I have made sure port 3000 is unblocked in the firewall, and the mobile device can access other servers running on other ports of the same computer.

Is there something else I need to setup in grunt?

Comment: just to be sure, you're not entering `127.0.0.1:3000` into the mobile browser, correct?

Comment: yeah, I do an ipconfig in cmd and grab that ip to use in the mobile browser

Comment: Any update on this? Did you manage to solve this?